# Continuous function $f$ differentiable implies that $f'$ is also differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

> Given a continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f$ is differentiable with derivative $f′$. Then $f′$ is differentiable again.

So my initial thoughts were that this isn't true but I really don't know! I was trying to think of a counter example such as maybe $f(x) = x^{0.5}$, with which $f'$ wouldn't be defined at $x=0$ and therefore not differentiable the second time.

EDIT;

Thanks guys for the speedy replies! I guess my solution wouldn't hold given that if x were negative I would end up with a complex root which wouldn't lie in the reals. I'll go with the |x| solution thank you!

Comment: Your proposed function $f(x) = x^{0.5}$ wouldn't be a counterexample because $f'$ fails to exist at $0$. leibnewtz's example $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x|x|$ serves your needs, but in case it matters, $f'$ needn't even be _continuous_, much less differentiable. The standard example is$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^{2} \sin(1/x) & x \neq 0, \\ 0 & x = 0.\end{cases}$$Remarkably, $f$ is differentiable _at every real number_; $f$', however, has an oscillatory discontinuity at $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=\int |x| dx$. Then $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=|x|$, which is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

"Every differentiable function is not $C^\infty$".

You **mean** "not every differentiable function is $C^\infty$.

"Every differentiable function is not $C^\infty$".  is equivalent to "if a function is differentiable then it is not $C^\infty$"  which is not what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial thoughts are good. This is not true, every differentiable function is not $C^{\infty}$. The situation is different for holomorphic functions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Examples